# Sell Android apps

Tags: android, google-play, merchant-account

I am confused with two things about Google Play 
[Supported locations for distributing applications](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/138294)

and [Supported locations for merchants](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/150324.)

I live in Pakistan. My question is can I sell apps on android play store? I have read about countries where developers can sell apps. But in allowed country merchant's page, my country is not listed. So what that means?

Comment: if i have answered your question can you vote up

Comment: Yes! of course. If your answer is correct, I will definitely vote up.

Comment: My answer is correct that y this question stack is closed

Comment: From Pakistan , you can publish android applications to Playstore, however, they have to be free. You can not publish applications for the purpose of selling. Please check this :- https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/136758

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your country is not listed in  Supported locations for distributing applications page that means you can't sell unless you have account in those particular country

Comment: But my country is listed in  "Developers in these locations may sell paid applications to users in the following countries" but not in "Supported locations for merchants". What that means?

Comment: That means in your country people can buy app from app store from other dev in selling country

Comment: @KhawarRaza hav you got it ?